# How to sort following list

Tags: c#, .net

I have following   `var result = new List<Tuple<int, List<ProductionReportEntry>, int>>();`

How I can sort it by the last integer , that the result will be from high to Low .

Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe this will work?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to use LINQ's `OrderByDescending()` extension method, it will sort your list in descending order from high to low and push it back into the list:

```
result = result.OrderByDescending(t => t.Item3).ToList();
```

That's assuming you want to store it back int the original reference, of course you could assign it to another variable, etc...

Alternatively, you could do an in-place sort using `List.Sort()`'s overload that takes a `Comparisson<T>` delegate:

```
// does descending since we put r on the lhs and l on the rhs...
result.Sort((l, r) => r.Item3.CompareTo(l.Item3));
```

Alternatively, you could build a custom `IComparer<T>`, of course for your `Tuple<int, List<PropertyReportEntry>, int>` but that gets pretty ugly looking...